# Using => operator to the logger from Serilog

Tags: c#

I know the `=>` operator can be used in lambda expression and expression body definition (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator). But I ran into this line of code recently, and I'm not sure why `=>` operator is used.

```cs
private static Serilog.ILogger Log => Serilog.Log.ForContext<DriverConfig>();
```

Would it works the same way if I change the => to = operator?  Like below:

```cs
private static Serilog.ILogger Log => Serilog.Log.ForContext<DriverConfig>();
```

Comment: With `=>` you have an expression bodied property, with `=` it's just a field. Property evaluated only once, field - every time. Btw, both your examples are the same

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I think you have that backwards, the property using `=>` will evaluate every time it's called, but the field with `=` will only evaluate once.  A property that only evaluates once would be `{ get; } = ...`

Comment: Another difference is that with `=>` it's a read only property so you cannot change it, but with `=` it's a field and you could change it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not lambda's but look and smell like them. They are [Expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

It reduces the amount of code for a more readable form. So in your example:

```
private static Serilog.ILogger Log => Serilog.Log.ForContext<DriverConfig>();
```

is equal to

```
private static Serilog.ILogger Log 
{
    get 
    {
        return Serilog.Log.ForContext<DriverConfig>();
    }
}
```

If you remove the `>` from the `=>` is all comes down to when the line is being executed. The first `=` is run when the static are being instantiated, and then its done, and will not be re-evaluated. The latter works as a get, and will be executed every time the get is called.

It looks the same, the behavior might be the same, but executions are different.

Comment: You're missing the `get` in the equivalent property.